# Execute the piped command when a condition is met

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop

## hadoop fs -ls ${DIRECTORY} | sort -k 6 | head -n -120 | awk '{ if ($5 == 0) print $8 }' | xargs hadoop fs -rm

I am trying to list files in a directory, sort them on time-stamp, skip the latest 120 files and delete the zero byte files in the remaining. Is there a way where I can skip the hadoop fs -rm part when there are no zero byte files?

Or can I do the same implementation using the timestamp(deleting the zero byte files that are created 30 minutes prior to the latest file).

Comment: Why do you want to skip it? If it is because it creates an error, you could either redirect the errors to /dev/null, or create a dummy, old, empty file before you start (using `touch`).

Answer (score 0):

You could run this in a for loop:

```
for file in `hadoop fs -ls ${DIRECTORY} | sort -k 6 | head -n -120 | awk '{ if ($5 == 0) print $8 }'`; do hadoop fs -rm $file; done
```

Or maybe this looks better:

```
files=`hadoop fs -ls ${DIRECTORY} | sort -k 6 | head -n -120 | awk '{ if ($5 == 0) print $8 }'`
if [ "$files" != "" ]; then echo "$files" |xargs hadoop fs -rm; fi
```